# How to replace a part of a string with a html tag?

Tags: jquery

How to replace a part of a string with a html tag in jQuery?
Say for e.g. `<div>Who am i</div>` should be `<div><b>Who</b> am i</div>`.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any special string processing functions, you can just use normal Javascript functions like `replace()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `html` method's callback function and `replace` method.

```
$('div').html(function(_, oldHTML){
   return oldHTML.replace(/(\w+)/, '<b>$1</b>');
   // return oldHTML.replace('Who', '<b>Who</b>');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3rAMp/

Comment: Oh.. Never heard that before

Answer (score 1):

use `.html()` of jquery

```
$("div").html("<b>Who</b> am i")
```