# How to add HTML tag for a specific part of the string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

> Please note that this question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674472/how-to-replace-a-part-of-a-string-with-a-html-tag) but the answer is provided in jQuery, I need similar thing to be done with vanilla javascript.

Here's my issue in detail. I have a price string to display in a page which will be in html as `<span>60.00</span>` I want to transform the string into something like this `<span>60,<sup>00</sup></span>`.

Here's the code I have tried.

```js
  let value = "60.00";
  value = value.replace(".", ",");
  let values = value.split(',');
  var tag = document.createElement("sup");
  var text = document.createTextNode(values[1]);
  text = tag.appendChild(text);
  let text1 = JSON.stringify(text);
  alert(values[0]+text1);
```

If I run this code I get `60{}` as an output. `60,⁰⁰` this is the desired output.

Comment: Please don't modify your question in a way it invalidates valid answers. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there with your current code but you're concatenating objects and strings. That doesn't work. You have to fill the elements one by one or convert the HTML elements to strings with `.outerHTML`:

```js
let value = "60.00";
value = value.replace(".", ",");
let values = value.split(',');
var tag = document.createElement("sup");
var text = document.createTextNode(values[1]);
tag.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = values[0];
document.getElementById('output').appendChild(tag);
alert(values[0] + tag.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I can't use innerHTML I'm using angular

Comment: @Viira Why can't you use innerHTML with Angular?

Comment: I'm using pipe `<span>{{foodItems.original_price | replace}}</span>`  I can't use pipes inside innerHTML

Comment: @Viira You should probably mention such constraints in your question.

Comment: I'll make new question then, thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Viira I edited my answer to create a HTML string. But you should know that Angular sanitizes HTML in strings. You can solve it with `<span innerHTML="{{foodItems.original_price | replace}}"></span>` or by using [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a `sup` tag, why not add the string `<sup></sup>` instead?

```js
let span = document.querySelector("span");
let value = span.innerHTML;

const sup = `<sup>${value.split('.')[1]}</sup>`;
value = `${value.split('.')[0]},${sup}`;

span.innerHTML = value;
```

```html
<span>60.00</span>
```

Comment: I have multiple span tags running on the page, it's a cart page. can we find the relative parent ?

Comment: I have tried your answer it works but it outputs as a string like this `60,<sup>00</sup>`

Comment: you can give class to the spans you want to change

Comment: How can I add class names for elements that are generating dynamically from a foreach loop

Comment: you must be writing generating the html in foreach loop just give it in that html

Comment: can you make a fiddle or codepen for that please!

Comment: value = `${value.split('.')[0]}.${sup}`;
change it to this for removing ,

Comment: would need your code of that line where you are creating this span in foreach

Comment: sure wait. It is in angular

Comment: not pretty sure about angular but i will try

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let span = document.querySelector("span");
let value = span.innerHTML;

const sup = `<sup>${value.split('.')[1]}</sup>`;
value = `${value.split('.')[0]}.${sup}`;

span.innerHTML = value;
```

```html
<span>10.00</span>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).